# Gridview items not populating correctly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have data I am trying to input into a gridview.  I am looking up the number of rows for the gridview and adding data into them like this:

My "test" however does not get populated into the Submitted and Variance BoundFields in the Gridview.  All that populates is the Company.  Shouldn't "test" also populate in those other two columns?

```
Private Sub BindGrid()

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Company")
    dt.Columns.Add("Submitted")
    dt.Columns.Add("Variance")
    gvTally.DataSource = dt


    Dim da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim strSQL2 As String
    Dim Response As String = ""

    strSQL2 = "SELECT [Company] FROM [Monetra].[dbo].[tbl_MonetraLogins]"
    da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strSQL2, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MainConnectionString").ToString)
    da.Fill(dt)

    Dim dr As DataRow

    For i As Integer = 0 To gvTally.Rows.Count - 1

        dr = dt.NewRow
        dr.Item("Company") = dt.Rows(i).Item("Company")
        dr.Item("Submitted") = "test"
        dr.Item("Variance") = "test"

        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next

    gvTally.DataSource = dt
    gvTally.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Here is my ASP Grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTally" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" 
                    AllowSorting="True" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="Small">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Company" HeaderText="Company" >
                        <ItemStyle Width="180px" />
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Submitted" HeaderText="Submitted" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Variance" HeaderText="Variance" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="False">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-small hidden-phone" Text="View" CommandName="View" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="60px" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this vb code behind, then comment out my test

```
Private Sub BindGrid()

    Dim dt_SQL_Results As New DataTable

    '' Commenting out to use test data as I have no access to your database
    'Dim da As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    'Dim strSQL2 As String
    'Dim Response As String = ""
    'strSQL2 = "SELECT [Company] FROM [Monetra].[dbo].[tbl_MonetraLogins]"
    'da = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(strSQL2, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MainConnectionString").ToString)
    'da.Fill(dt_SQL_Results)
    '' Commenting out to use test data as I have no access to your database

    '' Comment this block out after you test and uncomment the above code block
    dt_SQL_Results.Columns.Add("Company")
    Dim dr_SQL_Results As DataRow
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
        dr_SQL_Results = dt_SQL_Results.NewRow
        dr_SQL_Results.Item("Company") = "Company " & i
        dt_SQL_Results.Rows.Add(dr_SQL_Results)
    Next
    'gvTally.DataSource = dt_SQL_Results
    'gvTally.DataBind()
    '' Comment this block out after you test and uncomment the above code block

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Company")
    dt.Columns.Add("Submitted")
    dt.Columns.Add("Variance")

    Dim dr As DataRow
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt_SQL_Results.Rows.Count - 1
        dr = dt.NewRow
        dr.Item("Company") = dt_SQL_Results.Rows(i).Item("Company")
        dr.Item("Submitted") = "test"
        dr.Item("Variance") = "test"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next

    gvTally.DataSource = dt
    gvTally.DataBind()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you i see how you did it.